# Redirect PHP and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have a function that checks if the email address already exists in the database or not.

It's working:

Here's that portion.

```
->callback(function($val) 
{ 
    return !username_exists($val);
}, 'The username you entered already exists.')
->validate('username');
```

If the username exists, it will through a message saying "The username you entered already exists". What I want after 3 seconds this message is displayed redirects them to login page.

So I've added this line of code to the existing code:

```
wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php', sleep(3)); exit;
```

It does redirect, however I do not see the message anymore. Is there anyway I can display that message and then redirect?

It's a wordpress, so I can't do much in it.

Comment: How exactly is the message being displayed?

Comment: >It's a wordpress, so I can't do much in it.

why ? wordpres not opensourced anymore ?

Comment: I tend to stay away from pre-made CMSs, so I'm not familiar with Wordpress' code. I would imagine the message is displayed using javascript?

Comment: Yes, I do have a javascript that does print it. What Happens is that  I have a jquery colorbox where I have email, username, and password. If the email exists it takes it to the same page and shows a message. Now when I enter the redirect code, I don't see the message.

Comment: So when the user submits the form and the email exists, it displays a message on that page using jquery. 3 seconds later you want the user to be redirected to a different page? And you want that message to show up still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a HTML or JavaScript solution, not a php solution.

Here is an [HTML solution](http://www.instant-web-site-tools.com/html-redirect.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Page Title</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="3;url=http://localhost/wordpress/wp-login.php"></HEAD>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```